# Checking set equality using polynomials

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Assume we have to sets $A=\{a_1,\dots, a_{n_a}\}$, and $b=\{b_1,\dots, b_{n_a}\}$ where every element in these two sets are picked from $U=\{0,\dots, u-1\}$. It is then the case that
$$
A = B \iff \prod_{i=1}^{n_A} (x-a_i) = \prod_{i=1}^{n_B} (x-b_i)
$$
I then need help with understanding why it is the case that if we pick a prime $p\geq u$, then it holds that
$$
A=B \iff \prod_{i=1}^{n_A} (x-a_i) \equiv \prod_{i=1}^{n_B} (x-b_i) \quad (\text{mod }p)
$$

Comment: The forward implication is obvious. The backward implication works in the second case for the same reason it works in the first case: unique factorization of polynomials. Think about what fails when $p \lt u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first direction: $A=B$ implies $\prod_i (x-a_i) = \prod_i (x-b_i)$ should be clear, just because it does not matter for the product how we number the indices.

For the second direction, note that the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are the unique representatives of their congruence classes modulo $u$ between $0$ and $u-1$. Now assuming $\prod_i (x-a_i) \equiv \prod_i (x-b_i) \mod p$, then this means that for each $i$ in you index set, there is a unique $j$, also in your index set, such that $a_i \equiv b_j \mod p$ (this follows from the fact that $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ is an integral domain, a field even). After renumbering the $b_l$, we may assume $i=j$. So $a_i \equiv b_i \mod p$ for all $i$.

Now if there were an $i$, such that $a_i \neq b_i$, then write $b_i = a_i + np$, where $n \neq 0$ (we find such an integer $n$, because $a_i$ and $b_i$ are congruent modulo $p$). But $p \geq u$ by assumption, so because $b_i \geq 0$, we must have $n>0$, but also $b_i < u$, so $n < 1$. This is a contradiction, so $a_i = b_i$. We have this for all $i$, so $A=B$.

Hope this helps.